# Reference in c++ language

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I am learning c++ and I think everything is fine till now. I read about references and did some exercises(simple). But there is an understanding problem with this piece of code:

`const ints GetMax (const int& valuel, const int& value2)`.

Could anyone help me understand why it is passing references with the function name and what it will do(also in the type of its arguments)? What will reference do in this case???

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: thnx, very helpful too!!!

Comment: Also see [What is a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2765999/608639) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: also have a look at [Difference between const. pointer and reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336230/difference-between-const-pointer-and-reference)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A reference in C++ is *exactly* that, it's a variable name that refers to some other variable.

Think in terms of the statements:

```
int xyzzy  = 1;
int &plugh = xyzzy;
int twisty = xyzzy;
```

The actual "object" here for `xyzzy` is the thing containing the value `1`. You refer to it by its name `xyzzy` but that's really just a name for it.

The `plugh` is another reference to *exactly the same* underlying object - changing the value of `plugh` will also change the value of `xyzzy` since those are both names of (references to) the same thing.

The `twisty` variable, on the other hand, is created as a *new* object and simply copies the value of `xyzzy` across to it.

---

You'll often see things like:

```
void fn(const string &str1) { ... }
```

in code since it's more efficient to pass a reference to an object that's relatively expensive to construct/copy (like a string). Passing a reference to the object allows you direct access to the currently existing object, and making it `const` prevents the function from changing it.

It's very unusual to see this done with a basic type like `int` since the cost of duplicating them is very small, usually about the same as the cost of passing a reference to them.

You *will* occasionally see things like:

```
void fn(int &thing) { ... }
```

but that's usually because the `thing` is expected to be changed in the function and that change get mirrored back to the caller.

---

What your *particular* code is probably doing (though I can't be sure without more context) is not creating *any* new object, by virtue of the return of a reference. The following code shows, in my best guess, the sort of implementation it would have:

```
const int& GetMax(const int& value1, const int& value2) {
    if (value1 >= value2)
        return value1;
    return value2;
}
```

With that, the code:

```
int val1 = 7;
int val2 = 42;
const int &biggest = GetMax (val1, val2);
```

will actually set the *reference* `biggest` to refer to the largest of `val1` and `val2`. In other words, it's functionally equivalent to the pseudo-code:

```
val1 = 7
val2 = 42
if (val1 > val2)
    biggest = reference to val1
else
    biggest = reference to val2
```

Comment: thnx I got it, but what will reference do if we write it with type name like ***int&***?

Comment: But is there any advantage in passing `const int&` in parameter? Since it is `int` it does not provide any advantage regarding data coping and since it is `const` we can't change it. So what is the point of passing `const int&` instead of plain `int`?

Comment: @taskinoor: I've updated my answer based on the new info in the question. Because you want to return a *reference* to a variable, you need to use one whose lifetime extends beyond the function. In other words, pass-by-value parameters and locals are out of the equation.

Comment: @paxdiablo could you suggest better way of learning c++ please?(Or maybe there are some books which are easy to understand)

Comment: Sorry, @FirdavsbekNarzullaev, I suspect someone who's been using C++ for something like quarter of a century is probably the *least* qualified to advise on how to learn it :-)

Comment: okay) thnx anyway!

Comment: *"In other words, it's functionally equivalent to:..."* Not at all. You can't rebind a reference. Also you can't return a const reference and bind it to a non-const reference.

Comment: ...or for ex machine code programmers... "an index register that can't be changed"

Comment: @FirdavsbekNarzullaev Grab a [good book, like one our list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass int by reference, then it can't be modified from inside the function. Copies of the ints would be modified instead.