# Why no const reference in C++ just like const pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants, standards

```
int main()
{
    int        n = 1;
    int* const p = &n; // ok

    *p = 2; // ok as expected. 
    p  = 0; // error as expected.

    int& const m = n; 
    // error: 'const' qualifier may not be
    // applied to a reference   

    return 0;
}
```

Why no const reference in C++ just like const pointer?

What's the rationale behind the design?

Comment: What would you expect the `const` qualifier to prevent you from doing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[References](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) in C++ differ from pointers in several essential ways. One of the difference is:

> Once a reference is created, it cannot be later made to reference another object; it cannot be reseated. This is often done with pointers.

It means `Reference` are <strike>like</strike> similar (see the link at the end of this answer) to const pointer (**not pointer to a const!**) in C++...

```
int a = 5;
int& m = a; // Behaves similar to int * const m = &a;
// See the link at the bottom for the differences between const pointer and reference.
```

and hence, you can't change/rebind them to point to some other address. So, you don't need a explicit `const` qualifier for a reference and that's why it is disallowed by the compiler.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c) to learn `Why are references not reseatable in C++?`. I have copied the accepted answer of the above link:

The reason that C++ does not allow you to rebind references is given in Stroustrup's "Design and Evolution of C++" :

> It is not possible to change what a reference refers to after initialization. That is, once a C++ reference is initialized it cannot be made to refer to a different object later; it cannot be re-bound. I had in the past been bitten by Algol68 references where r1=r2 can either assign through r1 to the object referred to or assign a new reference value to r1 (re-binding r1) depending on the type of r2. I wanted to avoid such problems in C++.

**EDIT:**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336251/5735010) link for `Difference between const pointer and reference?` (Thanks to @M.M for pointing out the ambiguity in my statement).

Comment: There are various differences between a reference and a const pointer, this pedagogy is dangerous

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity in my statement. I have edited my answer!

Answer (score 4):

> Why no const reference in C++ just like const pointer?

References cannot be modified. Adding const qualification to non-modifiable entity would be meaningless and confusing.

Note that it is technically possible to apply const to a reference indirectly through a type alias or template type argument. Example:

```
T some_t;
using Ref = T&;
Ref const some_ref = some_t; // well-formed
```

`Ref const` type "collapses" into `T&`, and is same as unqualified `Ref`. I recommend to generally avoid creating type aliases for pointers and references, except for rare cases where they are conventional. Specifically, `Container::reference` type alias and similar are conventional.

Comment: How about `int n1, n2; int& m = n1; m = n2;`?

Comment: It might be better to say they can't be re-bound to another target (if that was indeed what you meant). References *can* be modified, it's just that modification is done to the target.

Comment: @xmllmx That modifies the referenced object. The reference remains unmodified i.e. it still refers to `n1`. Pointer equivalent is `int n1, n2; int* const m = &n1; *m = n2;` Notice how constness of the pointer doesn't prevent the assignment. Also, it has undefined behaviour since `n2` has indeterminate value.

Comment: @xmllmx, that changes the value of `m/n1`, it doesn't rebind the reference.

Answer (score 2):

```
  int& const m = n;
```

IMHO because it's inherently constant by compiler nature, just

```
 int n ;
```

`n` has ininherent constant reference

so as it is parsing codes it just determine to whichever place const qualifier is only allowed being there, by a compiler rule method for parsing, if not allowed then go to error/warning