# Object& const vs. const Object& vs. Object const &

Tags: c++, templates, constants, pass-by-reference

What is the difference between the following reference to a templated object in C++?

```
template<typename T>
void myFunction(Object<T>& const obj);

template<typename T>
void myFunction(const Object<T>& obj);

template<typename T>
void myFunction(Object<T> const & obj);
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694630/c-const-reference-before-vs-after-type-specifier) covers your second and third ones. The "templated" part is irrelevant. The `Object<T>& const` form is actually [quite misleading](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ref-nonsense) because it's equivalent to `Object<T>&` and not either of the apparent equivalents.

Comment: Although in practice [gcc refuses to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/dq985PxW9) a function with a parameter of type `int& const`, so that might just be entirely invalid syntax rather than a counterintuitive synonym for `int&`. Not sure of the standard language that would be definitive here.

Comment: Related (pointers instead of references): [What is the difference between `const int*`, `const int * const`, and `int const *`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Comment: A question to cover your first case: [Why no const reference in C++ just like const pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639756/why-no-const-reference-in-c-just-like-const-pointer)

Answer (score 4):

- `Object<T>& const obj` - is a const reference to non-const `Object<T>` (which doesn't make sense, because a reference cannot be rebound, it's always "constant");
- `const Object<T>& obj` - a reference to constant `Object<T>`;
- `Object<T> const& obj` - a reference to constant `Object<T>`, i.e. same as above (the `const` keyword applies to the right only if it cannot find anything to the left);